# Issues with deferring function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas

I have a function that basically makes a new div from existing divs and then generates an image from that. This all works fine. After this is complete, I'd like to `empty` and `hide` this new div. I thought I could use some deferred function to ensure that the new div doesn't `empty` before the function that makes the image is complete. If they happen at the same time or the `empty` happens first, then the image generated is blank (since the div is empty).

In my code, the function to empty and hide the new div is happening at the same time or before the function to make the image. How can I ensure that the function to empty and hide the new div comes after the function to create the image is entirely complete.

My code looks like this:

```
$('#export_all').click(function(){
    $('#gen_narr').hide();
    $("#full_complete").empty();

    var storyboard = $(this).closest('div').find(".full_storyboard");
    var nar_name = $(this).closest('div').find(".my_narrative_name");
    var nar_text = $(this).closest('div').find(".complete_narrative");

    $("#full_complete").append($(storyboard).html() + " " + $(nar_name).html() + " " + $(nar_text).html());
    full = $(this).closest('div').find("#full_complete");
    $.when(generateImg()).then(restoreIt());
});

function generateImg(callback) {
    html2canvas($(full), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            theCanvas = canvas;
            canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
                saveAs(blob, + "your_storyboard.jpg"); //this works
            });
        }
    });
}

function restoreIt() {
    $("#full_complete").hide();
    $('#gen_narr').show();
    console.log('restore'); //this works
}
```

Comment: you not actually using promises/deferreds here since your `generateImg` or `restoreIt` doesn't return anything. you need to create promise inside `generateImg` that will be resolved inside `onrendered`

Comment: can't use `$.when` on function that doesn't return a promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You not actually using promises/deferreds here since your `generateImg` or `restoreIt` doesn't return anything. you need to create promise inside `generateImg` that will be resolved inside `onrendered`

Try something like this

```
function generateImg(callback) {
    var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();

    html2canvas($(full), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            theCanvas = canvas;
            canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
                saveAs(blob, + "your_storyboard.jpg"); //this works
            });

            dfd.resolve( "hurray" );
        }
    });

    return dfd.promise();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. How do I then call `restoreIt`?

Comment: if it doesn't need to be promise too (you not calling anything after it right now) then you don't need to change it. it would be like this then `$.when(generateImg()).then(restoreIt);` () removed

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly and makes the concept of callbacks and promises much clearer. I'll accept this answer when I am able.